# what is the linux equivalent of "lorder" solaris command?

Tags: linux, makefile, linker, solaris

I'm trying to compile a sample code that should work both on Solaris and Linux. The make file on solaris run the command "lorder". There is a similar command for linux?

Thanks

Comment: `lorder` is available under some GNU/Linux distributions (e.g. Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)). What is yours? And, if it hasn't `lorder`by default, did you check what's available from your package manager?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine the fastest link order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367377/how-do-i-determine-the-fastest-link-order).  No equivalent is needed, so just **`:`** works in makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

lorder command was finding object files, I remember. I think you can use the updatedb and locate * .o command.

```
updatedb
locate *.o
```